# H2-H3 tags acting weird

Tags: html, css, tags, html-helper

My website is http://www.monstromidia.com/ but I am having problems with all my H2 to H6 tags. For example if you try to highlight it does not highlight normally also you can not copy any text in the "H" tag.

I already tried removing all rules to these tags but still nothing.

Please help.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Matt Ball, sorry this was my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using Cufon which renders a canvas image. In this image you are not able to select the letters since it is one image. You might want to consider using a custom font from https://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Do you by chance know how to remove cufon?

Comment: In your code you see Cufon.now(); My guess this executed Cufon. If this works do not forget to remove the cufon scripts you have included.

Comment: You dont know how thankful I am! Thank you x100

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just looked at your site and found that you have used "Cufon". Something like..

> <.cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Emails " style="width: 74px;
>   height: 26px;".> <.canvas width="97" height="32" style="width: 97px;
>   height: 32px; top: -5px; left: -1px;".> <./canvas><.cufontext>Emails
>   <./cufontext><./cufon>

What happening is, Cufon removes  text with an image, but there is text hidden behind it for screen readers. You can check that in "Inspect element", You should try changing its CSS so that it is positioned above or below the cufon text, and change its properties(like opacity) in such a way that it is not visible but selectable for users.

Comment: Thank you Rajat but i decided to remove the cufon scripts.